# Необходимость создания API интерфейсов в WEB приложении и основы проектирования?

Tags: ооп, php, проектирование

Задался в вопросом в необходимости API на одном из проектов, написанных на PHP Codeigniter.
Каковы основы и правила проектирования API? Как вообще это делается?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Это обычные GET или POST запросы обработанные на ваше усмотрение, но вместо авторизации через куки или сессию, вы используете уникальный ключ сгенерированный случайным образом и привязанный к пользователю. Название методовом зависит от вашей фантазии но делайте их интуитивно понятными. Так же обрабатывайте запросы регулярными выражениями по правилу "Можно только то, что разрешено"

Мне нравится структура вконтакте https://vk.com/dev/api_requests почитайте их документацию для пользователя и думаю для вас это будет хорошим мануалом